# Declare a reference property Non-Nullable?

Tags: c#, .net

One of my classes have a module, which I would like to replace, but I want to **throw an exception** when it is replaced with **null**.

I could make a normal setter, where I check the value, but I think that if I have more kind of modules, then it will be pretty ugly to have a null check in every setter.

Is there a way to define a property **Non-Nullable**? Or make a custom attribute?

```
public Module Module
{
     get; set;
}
```

Comment: `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in project file?

Comment: Depends on the version of .NET and C# you are using.

Comment: 4.0 unfortunately. Then nevermind.

Comment: C# 4.0 was released 10 years ago. The current version is 8.0. Are you really stuck with 4.0?

Comment: Not me, Unity :\